# Shorter way to pass two different parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

Apologies for the bad title, wasn't sure how to describe what I'm doing, my code is this:

```
        if (is_title === 'false') {
            $elem.popover({
                placement: 'auto',
                trigger: 'hover',
                html: true,
                delay: {"show": 0, "hide": 100},
                container: $elem,
                animation: true,
                template: '<div class="popover main_block popover_tweaks" style="width: 500px;" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
            });
        } else {
            $elem.popover({
                placement: 'auto',
                trigger: 'hover',
                html: true,
                delay: {"show": 0, "hide": 100},
                container: $elem,
                animation: true,
                template: '<div class="popover main_block popover_tweaks" style="width: 500px;" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="block_header"><h2 class="popover-title"></h2></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
            });

        }
```

I'm a (wannabe) php dev so I tried this (thinking it'd work like an array and I would be adding the last param but no go)

```
        $elem.popover({
                placement: 'auto',
                trigger: 'hover',
                html: true,
                delay: {"show": 0, "hide": 100},
                container: $elem,
                animation: true,
            });
        if (is_title === 'false') {
            $elem.popover({

                template: '<div class="popover main_block popover_tweaks" style="width: 500px;" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
            });
        } else {
            $elem.popover({

                template: '<div class="popover main_block popover_tweaks" style="width: 500px;" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="block_header"><h2 class="popover-title"></h2></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
            });

        }
```

My question is, is there a way to change only the template parameter without repeating all the others in my if else?

Comment: Use string interpolation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing an object literal. You can initialize it with the common parts first, then add the specific parts based on logic.

For example:

```
var param = {
            placement: 'auto',
            trigger: 'hover',
            html: true,
            delay: {"show": 0, "hide": 100},
            container: $elem,
            animation: true,
        }

if (is_title === 'false') {
    param.template = '<div class="popover main_block popover_tweaks" style="width: 500px;" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>';
} else {
    param.template =  '<div class="popover main_block popover_tweaks" style="width: 500px;" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="block_header"><h2 class="popover-title"></h2></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>';
}
$elem.popover(param);
```

Alternatively, you can use conditionals inside your object literal, so you could do something like this:

```
$elem.popover({
    placement: 'auto',
    trigger: 'hover',
    html: true,
    delay: {"show": 0, "hide": 100},
    container: $elem,
    animation: true,
    template: is_title ? 
        '<div class="popover main_block popover_tweaks" style="width: 500px;" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="block_header"><h2 class="popover-title"></h2></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>' 
        :'<div class="popover main_block popover_tweaks" style="width: 500px;" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>'
        });
```

Comment: Had no idea I could do either of those, that will help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Just use a conditional operator:

```
        $elem.popover({
            placement: 'auto',
            trigger: 'hover',
            html: true,
            delay: {"show": 0, "hide": 100},
            container: $elem,
            animation: true,
            template: (is_title === 'false' ? '<div class="popover main_block popover_tweaks" style="width: 500px;" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>' : '<div class="popover main_block popover_tweaks" style="width: 500px;" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="block_header"><h2 class="popover-title"></h2></div><div class="popover-content"></div></div>')
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an options object first and then use a ternary operator for your template. Something like:

```
`var opts = {template: title === false ? '<div>template 1</div>' : '<div>template 2</div>'};`
```

Then call

`popover(opts)`

Apologies for formatting!